# Application with lot of pictures in Android

Tags: android

My application will work with about 500 pictures - aprox 5Mb. The images will be displayed to the user one by one, among with a question. I would like to know what is the best way to store and access the images.

I am considering the following two options:

1. Saving the images on sd card. Is there a way to prevent user from seeing / deleting the images?
2. Saving the image data into database

Comment: If I get it right, the images will be downloaded when the app first starts?

Comment: saving image to database is not a good idea.

Comment: I haven`t decided yet on this aspect. I would prefer to be installed same time with the application, but downloading them on first run is also ok. I will go with which solution seems best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if this is the best way, but I've done thing the following way (in case the total size of pictures is 5Mb):

If you don't want to store them on SD card (for example, you pack the pictures with your application, not downloading and save them from the internet), so I recommend to put the picture files into the `assets` folder.

I suppose each question relates to one or several pictures, so you should use database (sqlite) to save the question text, and the path of relative pictures from the `assets` folder.

To display the picture, in an ImageView for example, you should load the Bitmap from the picture file in the `assets` folder. You may use a method like `ImageUtil.loadBitmapFromAssetNoThrow` in [this code](http://code.google.com/p/android-batsg/source/browse/android-batsg/src/com/chauhai/android/batsg/util/ImageUtil.java).

I think saving the image data into database makes it large and slow to access.

Comment: Yes, I have a database with 2000+ questions, and some of them also have pictures. I will go with this solution, which seems the best at the moment.
Thanks!